# JavaScript Youtube Search API v3: Clear Results, and Validation function

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've created an app that allows the user to retrieve the most viewed videos on Youtube. I want to include a validation function that will alert the user that they need enter the input on the search bar, as well as a function that will clear all of the search results and the input on the search bar. I'm kinda new to JavaScript, so I'm stuck on how to include those functions in my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="search.js" type="text/javascript"></script>        
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onClientLoad" type="text/javascript"></script>
         
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="query" placeholder="Enter video right here" type="text"/>
        <button onclick="search()">Search</button>
        <pre id="response"></pre>
    </body>
</html>

<!--Code from tpl/item.html-->
<div class="item">
    <h2>{{title}}</h2>
    <iframe class="video w100" width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/{{videoid}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> function that will alert the user that they need to enter the input on
>   the search bar

In your search() function, add a conditional to check if a value has been entered.  If true, run the code you have listed. If false, alert().

```
function search(){
  if(document.getElementById('query').value.trim().length > 0){
    // your code
  } else {
    alert('please enter a value into the search');
  }
}
```

> function that will clear all of the search results and the input on the search bar

To clear any value or inner HTML of an element, set element.value or element.innerHTML equal to nothing. Examples:

```
document.getElementById('query').value = '';
document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = '';
```

Comment: I added your code, and I was able to get them to work! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="search-wrap">
    <input id="query" placeholder="Enter video right here" type="text"/>
    <button onclick="search()">Search</button>
    <pre id="response"></pre>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // get submit button DOM
    const buttonSubmit = $('yourSubmitButton');
    // when you click the submit button
    buttonSubmit.click(function() {
        const searchValue = $(this).parent('.search-wrap').find('#query').val();
        if(searchValue === '') {
            alert('You must input something');
            return false;
        } 

        /* Do whatever you want in here*/
        search();

        /* clear result after search */
        $(this).parent('.search-wrap').find('#query').val('');
    })
})
```

I wrap your HTML code in '.search-wrap', end use jQuery if you want. For more information search jQuery DOM tree traversing